# How to ask for Admin with batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, registry

I want to make a batch file which enables the ***Seconds*** in the Taskbar ***(There where you see the time)***.

I know you can do that manually when you open registry editor and go to

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

And create there a ***DWORD-Value (32-Bit)*** and name it ***ShowSecondsInSystemClock*** and set the value on 1 and then Restart the Computer.

But now I want to make this in a batch file and that the User gets asked to enter his Password (The Password of the Computer) to continue (to make sure it is really the owner of the Computer). Is there a way to do that?

I'm really new to batch and I have only done basic stuff until now, I'm collecting my first experiences with programming.

Comment: To make this change, an end user does not need to be elevated nor are they required to enter a password on a Windows system unless it has been configured specifically to do that. Perhaps you should explain your environment and show us the code you are using, so that we can replicate it, and better understand. The following ran from a batch file or directly in a Command Prompt window should generally perform the task without issue: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /V ShowSecondsInSystemClock /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F 1>NUL```

Comment: You do not necessarily need to restart the PC, although it is the simplest way to affect the change, (you may find that restarting explorer.exe is sufficient). If you open a Command Prompt window, type `shutdown /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key, you can learn how to use it. _(You may wish to do the same with `taskkill /?`, and `start /?` if you wish to consider restarting explorer.exe)._

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, it is very Helpful. I havn't written any code, i just wanted to know if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the comment above posted by @Compo:

You don't need admin rights to change this setting in registry

And you don't need to restart the computer, just restart the ***exploer process***

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Show Or Hide Seconds In System Clock
Color 9E & Mode 80,10 & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
::--------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetInfo
@REM Get Opened Folders with PowerShell code in a batch file
Set PSCommand="@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | ForEach { $_.Self.Path }"
REM  Populate the array with existent and opened folders
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /a Count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Powershell -C %PSCommand%') do (
    Set /a Count+=1
    Set "Folder[!Count!]=%%a"
)
::===========================================================================
:menuLOOP
::===========================================================================
echo(
echo(
echo(       ***************************** Menu ******************************
echo(
@for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do (
echo(                 %%A  %%B)
echo(
echo(       *****************************************************************
echo( &Set /p Selection=Make a Selection or hit ENTER to quit: || Goto :EOF
echo( & Call:menu_[%Selection%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::===========================================================================
::---------------------------------
:menu_[1] Show Seconds In SystemClock
reg Add "%Key%" /V ShowSecondsInSystemClock /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F 1>NUL
Call:Restart_Explorer
@rem Restore all closed folders
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Start /MAX Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------
:menu_[2] Hide Seconds In SystemClock
reg Add "%Key%" /V ShowSecondsInSystemClock /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL
Call:Restart_Explorer
@rem Restore all closed folders
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Start /MAX Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------
:Restart_Explorer
powershell -C "gps explorer | spps"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------
```

---

***Remark about alias used in PowerShell command to restart the explorer process:***

`gps` is the [Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-5.1) for [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-5.1)

`spps` is the alias for [Stop-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Stop-Process?view=powershell-5.1)